# presentModalViewController from tab bar in storyboard

Tags: xcode

I am doing the following in viewDidAppear:

```
SettingsViewController *svc = [[SettingsViewController alloc]init];   
[self presentModalViewController:svc animated:YES];
```

It appears to do something, but it doesn't seem to put the view controller on top.

In my storyboard I have one tab view which launches and I verified the method is being called, but the view controller doesn't display as it should. Do I have to hook up this view controller some how in the storyboard?

Answer (score 1):

That's because the storyboard doesn't accept the orders you're giving to your Navigation Controller. 
Try this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"SettingsViewController"]) {
    [segue destinationViewController];
    }
}
```